# How to remove unwanted elements from ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list wilth values

```
ArrayList<String> HexValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    HexValues.add("a");
    HexValues.add("b");
    HexValues.add("f");
    HexValues.add("1");
    HexValues.add("4");
    HexValues.add("0");
    HexValues.add("31");
    HexValues.add("32");
    HexValues.add("37");
    System.out.println("The content of HexValues is: " + HexValues);


    int start = HexValues.lastIndexOf("f");

    if (start != -1) {
        List<String> HexValuesEnd = HexValues.subList(start, HexValues.size());


        System.out.println("The content of HexValuesEnd before leaving is: " + HexValuesEnd);
        if (HexValuesEnd.size() > 0) {               

            HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
            HexValuesEnd.remove(2);
            HexValuesEnd.remove(3);
            System.out.println("The content of HexValuesEnd after removing values at indexes 1 ,2,3: " + HexValuesEnd);
        }
    }
```

The out put is

```
The content of HexValues is: [a, b, f, 1, 4, 0, 31, 32, 37]
The content of HexValuesEnd  before leaving is: [f, 1, 4, 0, 31, 32, 37]
The content of HexValuesEnd after removing values at indexes 1 ,2,3: [f, 4, 31, 37]
```

but the expected values in second array list should be

```
"The content of HexValuesEnd after removing values at indexes 1 ,2,3: " [f,31,32,37]
```

where am i going wrong to get the expected results..

Answer (score 5):

When you remove one of the values, the values after it are shifted to fill the gap.

What you mean to do is

```
remove(1);
remove(1);
remove(1);
```

Comment: it's working fine after changing code to remove(1);remove(1);remove(1);.thanks a lot for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

It's because after

```
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
```

the arraylist is

[f, 4, 0, 31, 32, 37]

Now it executes

```
HexValuesEnd.remove(2);
```

so you get

[f, 4, 31, 32, 37]

an so on...

What you need to do is

```
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You had `[f, 1, 4, 0, 31, 32, 37]`

Then you remove at index 1 and get `[f, 4, 0, 31, 32, 37]`

Then index 2: `[f, 4, 31, 32, 37]` (index 2 was `0` in the list after the first remove)

And so on.

Keep in mind that remove changes the List.

Seems you wanted to remove index `1` 3 times:

```
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
```

Comment: it's working fine after changing code to remove(1);remove(1);remove(1);.thanks a lot for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if (HexValuesEnd.size() > 0) {               
                HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
                HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
                HexValuesEnd.remove(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is use a functional programming library that supports the higher-order method of filter.  I know that Apache-commons, Guava, and lambdaJ, all support filter.

Here is some sudo code on what the synatx would look like:

```
Predicate predicate = new Predicate(){{
    public boolean evaluate(Object object){
     // If statement comparison goes here
    }
}};
filter(HexValuesEnd, predicate);
```

Since this is native java you'll need to make a predicate object to preform a check for each element within a collection and each library has their own way of doing this.

Apache-commons and Gauva has their own predicate object, while lambdaJ is built on top of hamcrest and uses it's matcher's as predicate objects.

Also an add benefit besides small, highly readable code is that these libraries should have built-in concurrency optimization so  you don't have to deal with threads if you want to boost performance.

Also be careful with .remove, if you use it within a loop, you're gonna have a bad time.  If you want to want iterative approach to remove elements from a collection try using an iterator instead.